# Error when I try to install npm on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm-install

I'm trying to install npm on Ubuntu 17.04 but I'm not getting it. I've installed nodejs and nodejs-legacy and when I try to install npm, a message appears saying that npm depends on node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) and won't be installed. If a try to install node-gyp, another dependency appears and successively. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you don't use apt-install to install npm.You can download the bin file from official site.(https://nodejs.org/en/)

Just extract the tar file and setup the path to you system,you can get the latest version!

Comment: JWang, I've solved just doing curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash - and then apt get install nodejs. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This method requires trusting MANY parties and then giving full access to your computer to deb.nodesource.com, an entity that can't even be bothered to update their website each version to include the content hash for your security. No thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you use apt-get for install nodejs you can switch version easily:

```
$ sudo apt-get install npm # install npm
$ sudo npm install -g  n  # install n nodejs version switcher as global package.
$ sudo n stable # install latest stable version.
```

install more version: [exmp: 9.1.0]

```
$ sudo n 9.1.0
```

[reference](https://github.com/tj/n)